# How to change value of an object that is a value inside another object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am passing values to the function addPolyline(props) to change the path value and color dynamically

```
var lineSymbol = {
    path: 'M 0,-1 0,1',
    strokeOpacity: 1,
    scale: 4,          
    strokeWeight: 2,
};



function addPolyline(props){    
    flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({ 
        path: props.flightPath,
        geodesic: true,
        strokeColor: props.color,
        strokeOpacity: 0,
        icons: [{
            icon: lineSymbol,
            offset: '0',
            repeat: '20px'
        }]
    });
}   

addPolyline({
    flightPath: flightPlanCoordinates,
    color: "#f9a61e"
});
```

But how do I change the opacity which is inside lineSymbol but called in addPolyline as part of icon key.

Comment: Can't you modify lineSymbol before the initialization of `flightPath`? Something like: `lineSymbol.strokeOpacity = props.newOpacity`.

Comment: Assuming that you can have multiple icons, you will have to loop over the icons and merge/override the objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need just to initialize the value in lineSymbol using your `props` to pass the required value

```
function addPolyline(props){  
   lineSymbol.strokeOpacity = props.symbolOpacity;   
   flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({ 
    ...
```

or, if you don't want to modify the global `lineSymbol`

```
 function addPolyline(props){  
   var symbol = Object.assign({}, lineSymbol)
   symbol.strokeOpacity = props.symbolOpacity;   
   flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({ 
     ...
     icons: [{
        icon: symbol,
```

and invoke with

```
addPolyline({
    flightPath: flightPlanCoordinates,
    color: "#f9a61e",
    symbolOpacity: 0.8
});
```

Comment: Even now only the color changes, not the opacity

Comment: oops small typo, fixed.

Comment: This works, thank you, So I will have to assign the object to the outer-object and then call the assigned object key